# load Dictionary into table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I’m reading a string from a file and convert it into Dictionary but I can’t load it in a tableview : here is my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {




        let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("x").appendingPathExtension("json")
         filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "x", ofType: "json")


        do {

          let  readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            let x = readString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
              do{

                            }catch{
                                 print (" error nil  ")
                                }

            for i in 1..<x.count{
                do{
                let y = x[i]


                var b = convertToDictionary(text: y)


                    let date = try b?["date"]
                    dictarr["date"] = "\(date)"
                     print (" midas \(dictarr["date"])  ")

                    let response = try b?["response"]!
                    dictarr["response"] = "\(response)"
//                    print (" midas \(dictarr["response"])  ")

                    let message = try b?["message"]
                    dictarr["message"] = "\(message)"
//                    print (" midas \(dictarr["message"])  ")

                    clinetarr.add(dictarr)

            }catch{
                print (" error nil  ")
            }
            }







        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }



    func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print ("nil found")
                //print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

and here is my table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let datainrow = clinetarr[indexPath.row]
 cell.textLabel?.text = "\((datainrow as AnyObject).object("message")!)"

   cell.textLabel?.text=itemListTmp[keysItem[indexPath.section]]?.removeFirst()
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

in this line,   cell.textLabel?.text = "((datainrow as AnyObject).object("message")!)" it gives me error:  call value of non-function type 'Any' my main goal is to display: dictarr["date"], dictarr["response"] and dictarr["message"] each in a line inside one cell.

Comment: Why not do some basic research on how to use a table view, there are plenty of tutorials to be found.

Comment: i did that already, otherwise i wont be here.

Comment: Then what exactly is your problem with using a table view?

Comment: i update my post with more details. i appreciate that u r trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you read from your dictionary is not correct, you should cast each value to its correct type. I don't know what types you have for your values but if we assume they are all of type String I would do something like this

```
var output: String = ""

if let date = dictarr["date"] as? String {
    output = "\(date) "  //using space as separator
}

if let response dictarr["response"] as? String { 
    output.append(response)
    output.append(" ")
}

if let message dictarr["message"] as? String { 
    output.append(message)
}

cell.textLabel?.text = output
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot  @Joakim Danielson

i just managed to solve it few hours ago here is how i did it:

```
 for i in 1..<x.count{
                do{
                    if x != nil {

                let y = x[i]

                    let  b =  convertToDictionary(text: y)


                        if let date = try b?["date"]{
                            dictarr["date"] = "\(date)"
                        }
                        if  let response = try b?["response"]{
                            dictarr["response"] = "\(response)"
                        }

                        if let message = try b?["message"]{
                            dictarr["message"] = "\(message)"
                        }
                    clinetarr.append(dictarr)
                    }
            }catch{
                print (" error nil  ")
                }
            }
```

and here is tableview:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

            let client = clinetarr[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.textLabel?.text = client["response"] as! String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(client["message"] as! String) \n \( client["date"] as! String)"


return cell
    }
```